# Parse.com reducing high volume of request

Tags: c#, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have just transferred my app from a MySQL solution to parse.com, and are happy so far, but... I am constantly trying to find ways to improve the performance and have a question.

If I have a function in my app in which I have to request parse.com 3 times (3 queries), would it be possible to reduce this to one time if I made the 3 requests in a cloud code and just requested the cloud code (1 query), or would that make it 4 request (4 queries)?

Hope someone can help me cast some light on this matter.

Thanks in advance and Happy New Year ;-)

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer:
https://www.parse.com/questions/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-api-requests

If you are going to use cloud code it will cause 4 requests, 1 for calling the cloud method and 3 for query within cloud code.